# Error while executing queries in spark console of wso2das

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

I'm trying to create few temporary tables in spark console of wso2das. But after I run the command, it keeps on executing providing no results. Below is the error which I'm getting from the logs file.

```
TID[-1234] [DAS] [2016-02-08 09:12:57,777] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver} - Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method execute sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) 
org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212) org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117) 
org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40) org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110) 
org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180) org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:169) 
org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:82) 
org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.local.CarbonLocalTransportSender.finalizeSendWithToAddress(CarbonLocalTransportSender.java:45) org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportSender.invoke(LocalTransportSender.java:77) 
org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442) org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:430) 
org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225) org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149) 
org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.admin.stub.AnalyticsProcessorAdminServiceStub.execute(AnalyticsProcessorAdminServiceStub.java:1080) 
org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.ui.client.AnalyticsExecutionClient.executeScriptContent(AnalyticsExecutionClient.java:67) 
org.apache.jsp.spark_002dmanagement.executeScript_005fajaxprocessor_jsp._jspService(executeScript_005fajaxprocessor_jsp.java:133) org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395) 
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155) 
org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) 
org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37) org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61) 
org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128) org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68) 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68) 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) 
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CSRFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CSRFPreventionFilter.java:88) 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) 
org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CRLFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CRLFPreventionFilter.java:59) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61) 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) 
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504) org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) 
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99) 
org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47) org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57) 
org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:48) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47) 
org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159) 
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57) 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421) 
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074) org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611) 
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739) org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698) 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) 
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Please let me know what's to be done

Comment: Can you please provide the spark query you used to create the temporary tables?

Comment: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table2 using CarbonJDBC options (dataSource "DASConnection_Raw", tableName "pet");

Comment: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table1 using CarbonJDBC options (dataSource "DEV_DB", tableName "MyMicrosLogTable");
The table above belongs to mssql 

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table2
USING CarbonAnalytics 
OPTIONS (tableName "demostream");

WSO2DAS has been installed in the remote system and I'm executing these queries in the spark console. Locally, I'm getting the required output but in remote system the queries keep on executing without providing any output.